# Why my asp.net identity -user will log out automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api2

I have a project that have asp.net MVC and asp.net WebApi.

I don't know why User log out automatically, for example when I close browser and after 15 minutes I see that I need to login again and after I redirect user to bank website for payment when the bank website redirect user again to my web site it need to login again.

I use asp.net identity authentication cookie, below is in my **StartUp.cs** file code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Issuer = "http://localhost:37993/";

        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //app.UseMvc(RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes);

        //ConfigureWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    }
    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new LeitnerContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<LeitnerUserManager>(LeitnerUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<LeitnerRoleManager>(LeitnerRoleManager.Create);

        // Plugin the OAuth bearer JSON Web Token tokens generation and Consumption will be here

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/User/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsForApi(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15),
            Provider = new LeitnerOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new LeitnerJwtFormat(Issuer),
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
        //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }

    private bool IsForApi(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
        return ((headers != null) && ((headers["Accept"] == "application/json") || (request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))));
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var a = AudiencesStore.AudiencesList["LeitnerAudience"];
        string audienceId = a.ClientId;// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(a.Base64Secret/*ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]*/);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(Issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this problem is there?

Comment: How does your authentication cookie looks like in browser/fiddler ? Is it by any chance session cookie ?

Comment: @mohsen , any chance that in your DB is securitystamp  field null ? can you confirm once

Comment: @Webruster What is securitystamp in db? i don't khow how asp.net identity work exactly.is any where an tutorila to learn it correctly?how can i use secutrystamp?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I don't khow.how can i see that cookie?

Comment: @mohsen did in you sqlserver db , you will be having a column about the securitystamp, check whether its der or not and if it is present what is the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for users logging off is because of error in the validation of forms-authentication data and view-state data. It could happen for different reasons including using web farm in hosting services.You should check `<machineKey>` in your project **webconfig**.

If you don't have `<machineKey>` in your `webconfig`, try adding this piece of code after `<system.web>` in your `webconfig`:

```
<machineKey
      validationKey="someValue"
      decryptionKey="someValue"
      validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

There are some online tools from where you can generate machine key. You can check [this](http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx) and [this](http://chaos.aspnet.cz/).

You can learn more about machine key from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15)` is being ignored..

I use the TimeSpan like this:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
          {
             OnValidateIdentity =  SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
          },
          SlidingExpiration = false,
          ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
```

Added the missing code from the configuration.
Also, if you have the option 'Remember me' make sure you have it configured in the login method.

```
var login = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: I forgot some code I use in the app.. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

"Logging out automatically after 15 mins" happens due to this code.

```
TimeSpan.FromDays(15)
```

If you omit this code, you will get the result you want or 
in normal, this value is set by 60 * 24 = 1440 (mins - 1 day).
So common expiration time is one day.
But you set it 15 minutes so that problem occurred.

Comment: It says very clearly `TimeSpan.FromDays(15)`; this is 15 days, not 15 minutes.