# Session value will lost asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net MVC and webapi2 application.I want to set OrderId in session and send User to bank website to pay the order and when the bank website will return him to my callback URL in my website I want to get OrderId from the session but it seems that is null. I want to know why it happens?

and another problem is that I use cookie authentication in identity but it doesn't work too. I have set it to 15 days .but it doesn't work too.I don't know but maybe these two problems are related to each other.if someone knows

[Why my asp.net identity -user will log out automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994611/why-my-authentication-cookie-will-remove-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
public ActionResult Pay()
{
    Session["orderid"]=12;
}

//callbackurl
public ActionResult Result()
{
   var orderid=Convert.ToInt32( Session["orderid"]);//is null
}
```

the below is in my web.config

```
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="30">
      </forms>
    </authentication>    
    <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

and the below is in startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Issuer = "http://mywebsite.ir/";

        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //app.UseMvc(RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes);

        //ConfigureWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    }
    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new LeitnerContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<LeitnerUserManager>(LeitnerUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<LeitnerRoleManager>(LeitnerRoleManager.Create);

        // Plugin the OAuth bearer JSON Web Token tokens generation and Consumption will be here

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/User/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsForApi(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15),
            Provider = new LeitnerOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new LeitnerJwtFormat(Issuer),
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }

    private bool IsForApi(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
        return ((headers != null) && ((headers["Accept"] == "application/json") || (request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))));
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var a = AudiencesStore.AudiencesList["LeitnerAudience"];
        string audienceId = a.ClientId;// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(a.Base64Secret/*ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]*/);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(Issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

My WebHost is Plesk Onyx,In the **Hosting Setting** I see a setting **Preferred domain** that have three item to select

1- www.jooyabash.ir

2- jooyabash.ir

3- None

Description :Select the URL (either with or without the www. prefix) to which site visitors will be redirected via a SEO-safe HTTP 301 redirect.

When I set it to **1** or **3** i see that session will lost.but when i set it to **2** session until 10 min it will not lost and the payment will compelet in this time

Does any one know why?

Comment: How do you apply request for "Pay" and "Result" ?

Comment: @rainman After the user paid the order the bank website will redirect the user to result action and the pay action  is when the user in prepayment page he click the pay button

Comment: have you tried setting a variable and accessing it like this for example 
`int orderId= (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["orderid"];`.

Comment: Yes I use it like that in an library 'HttpContext.Current.Session["orderid"];' but it is null